# Exception.log is missing in Magento2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, magento2.4.5

While exception is generated the exception.log file is missing inside the var/log folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vardhman Kamani

We have verified this issue in our local environment and found work around(temporary) solution for it.

File path where need to replace core code:
vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/System.php

Please replace below code:

```
public function write(array $record): void
    {
        if (isset($record['context']['exception'])) {
            $this->exceptionHandler->handle($record);

            return;
        }
        $record['formatted'] = $this->getFormatter()->format($record);

        parent::write($record);
    }
```

With :

```
public function write(array $record): void
    {
            
        if (isset($record['context']['exception']) || $record['level'] == Logger::CRITICAL) {
            $this->exceptionHandler->handle($record);

            return;
        }
        $record['formatted'] = $this->getFormatter()->format($record);

        parent::write($record);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @SamirShaikh It's working for me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @VardhmanKamani

Fine, Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Does not work. Tested with 2.4.4-p3